# Squeryl ORM fails using Long, bigints, and operators?

Tags: scala, squeryl

Squeryl just isn't having it today. I've got a nasty error that I have so far unsuccessfully worked around.

The error thrown by Postgres:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while executing statement : ERR
OR: operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need
to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 722
```

Not sure why this error is thrown, except that I am storing a Scala Long in a bigint field and then running queries on it. Am I doing something wrong?

All of this runs on the Squeryl ORM so I'm 90% confident my types are correct. My code compiles, too.

## Edit

This is literally the code I'm using to query. Not much...

```
from(DB.relays)(r =>
where((r.userId === userId))
select (r))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a terrible person.

Spent nearly two hours on this, but it all came down to a poisonous database evolution.

I had no idea, and I'm confused on how it got away, but that `userId` column was actually a `text` field. I didn't find the error until I started printing table structure.

I'm shocked at how it got in there without being detected since I was entering records like crazy with no errors.

Comment: It takes real strength of character to admit when you've done something that awful.  Have an upvote.

Comment: Thank you kind one, my tears do not feel so salty anymore.